# Determining a group given some elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Say we have a group G and we know some of the elements (but not all). How does one determine the order and list all the elements of the group in an intuitive way?

In this case G is the smallest subgroup of $S_4$, and it contains the permutations $\tau_1 = (2,3,4)$, $\tau_2 = (1,3,4)$, $\tau_3 = (1,2,4)$, $\tau_4 = (1,2,3)$, and $\mu_{12}=(1,2)(3,4)$, $\mu_{13}=(1,3)(2,4)$, $\mu_{14}=(1,4)(2,3)$.

What i want to do: find the order of G and list all the elements of G by using the symbols above and give the corresponding permutations.

My thought process so far: 
$S_4$ has $4! = 24$ which means that G's order must be a divisor (possibilities are 8, 12, 24 ignoring 1,2,3,4 and 6). Since G is a group, it must contain the identity element, the inverses for all elements mentioned above, and all possible products of the elements*.

- is where I get stuck, because one has many possibilities? Hence why i think i am missing something. How does one go about this?

Comment: Since there is no odd permutation in the given list, $G$ is a subgroup of $A_4$. Then $|G|$ divides $12$ and since $8\leq |G|$ we have the equality. Since you are asking a much more general question (most probably which does not have an answer) I leave this as a comment.

Comment: For me the most intuitive way would be, denoting the list of elements you start with by $x_1,...,x_n$, to consider successively the subgroups $\langle x_1\rangle$, $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$ and so on.

In this case @Levent has a more efficient solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you may note that all listed permutation are even, so you are within $A_{4}$, of order $12$. Your group has at least $8$ elements, but then it has elements of order $3$, so it cannot have $8$ elements.

You may finish noting that 
$$
V = \{ 1, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3) \}
$$
is a (normal) subgroup of $A_{4}$, and the elements of $A_{4}$ outside $V$ have all order $3$.

To obtain all the elements of order $2$ from the given elements, try conjugating $(123)$ and $(234)$ by the elements of $V$. For instance
$$
(123)^{(12)(34)} = (214).
$$

Comment: So one eliminates 8 because 8 is not divisible by 3, but one still has to decide if G has order 12 or 24?

Comment: @clueless it does not because as Andreas stated in the first lines $G$ must be a subgroup of $A_4$ hence its order must divide $12$ and so it cannot be $24$.

Comment: Nice. I have one stupid question:  So. when listing all the elements of the group there are 4 'unknown' elements (because the identity element and the 7 permutations are given), one finds the inverse element for each permutation ? And then since we only can have 4 extra elements, these inverse elements are either included in G as one of the initial 7?

Comment: The identity, and the products of two disjoint two-cycles, are their own inverses. Then the group will contain all the three-cycles, and the inverse of the three-cyclke $(abc)$ is the three-cycle $(cba)$.